# Android bottom navigation bar hiding AdMob adverts

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've got an odd bug here with Xamarin Forms on my droid project. The bottom navigation bar (i.e the one with the home, back etc buttons) is hiding the AdMob adverts. If I choose to hide it by double tapping the circle (on the navigation bar), the advert appears, and when I double tap the circle again to make the navigation bar re-appear the ads display. But unless I hide the navigation bar, you would never know the advert is there!

I've tried setting various options under the SystemUIVisility and nothing is working. I even got the app into full screen mode and set the navigation bar to hidden but the adverts still did not appear.

Has anyone else had this issue and found a fix?

I'm using Forms 3.3.0.912540, Xamarin.Firebase.Ads 60.1142.1, Xamarin.GooglelayServices.Ads 60.1142.1

Comment: Did you submitted this as an issue on github.com/xamarin/xamarin.forms?

Comment: No not yet, think I may do though, just wanted to see if anyone else has experienced this issue at all and found a work around

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:
add property to your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```